# (QGIS) Shapefile with attribute table: Convert it to raster burning values of each polygon to the raster. "Heatmap"

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, rasterization, raster-conversion

I am working on QGis with a shapefile with an attribute table, I have created this shapefile through "Vector->Analysis tools->Count Points in Polygon", so this new shapefile got the count in the attribute table.

[image]

---

I want to convert now this shapefile to a "heatmap" in raster format.

I am trying to do it with "Raster->Conversion->Rasterize", burning the values of the attribute table

---

[image]

In those polygons with number=0 QGIS doesn't draw the polygons in the raster.

---

[image]

---

I would like to get all those polygons filled in the raster, I know I could erase all those polygons in the attribute table with data, then change all the 0s to 1, and then rasterize it, merging both rasters (the original with empty polygons and the new one with only the "empty" polygons filled).
I think this is just too tricky .

Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Rasterize tool, notice the option to set a nodata value:

> Assign a specified nodata value to output bands [optional]

You have 0.000000 set as the optional nodata value, so all polygons with 0 in their burning field are converted to nodata values in the raster.

Clear the nodata value by clicking the X button in the nodata box: [image]

Comment: Thanks!, I was setting burn value to 1.0000 also, I didn't know that burn value could be empty.